# ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Syntax error (missing operator)

Tags: sql, excel, odbc

Trying to access an Excel file as database using ODBC driver. and need to join 3 tables (Sheets1,2,3) in excel WB using following query :

```
"select [Sheet1$]." + CompanyCode_ColName + 
", [Sheet1$]." + CompanyName_ColName +
", [Sheet1$]." + GLAccountNumber_ColName +
", [Sheet1$]." + GLAccountName_ColName +
", [Sheet1$].EndingBalance1, [Sheet2$].EndingBalance2,[Sheet3$].EndingBalance3 " +
"from [Sheet1$] left join [Sheet2$] " +
"on [Sheet1$]." + GLAccountNumber_ColName +
" = [Sheet2$]." + GLAccountNumber_ColName +
" left join [Sheet3$] " +
"on [Sheet3$]." + GLAccountNumber_ColName +
" = [Sheet1$]." + GLAccountNumber_ColName
```

I get this error when joining the 3 tables as shown above:

> Run query: ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[Sheet1$].GLAccNum =  [Sheet2$].GLAccNum left join [Sheet3$] on [Sheet3$].GLAccNum =  [Sheet1$].GLAccNu'.

But it's okay when I join just 2 tables!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the MS Access SQL dialect of which the Excel ODBC connection uses, parentheses are required for more than one join. Hopefully, the MS team heeds my [feedback ticket](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/2b2671a8-b67b-ec11-a81b-000d3a7c83cc) (among other items) to change this frustrating syntax requirement on future versions.

Therefore, wrap the first `FROM-JOIN` pair after `ON` in parentheses.

```vb
"from ([Sheet1$] left join [Sheet2$] " +          ' OPENING PARENETHESIS
"on [Sheet1$]." + GLAccountNumber_ColName +
" = [Sheet2$]." + GLAccountNumber_ColName +
") left join [Sheet3$] " +                        ' CLOSING PARENETHESIS
"on [Sheet3$]." + GLAccountNumber_ColName +
" = [Sheet1$]." + GLAccountNumber_ColName
```

Consider also a replace method for readability of your SQL. Below uses table aliases and shows two parentheses pairs which can also resolve your syntax issue.

```vb
Dim var As variant
...

strSQL = "SELECT s1.%CompanyCode_ColName%" _ 
       & "     , s1.%CompanyName_ColName%" _
       & "     , s1.%GLAccountNumber_ColName%" _
       & "     , s1.%GLAccountName_ColName%" _
       & "     , s1.%EndingBalance1%" _ 
       & "     , s2.%EndingBalance2%" _
       & "     , s3.%EndingBalance3%" _
       & " FROM (([Sheet1$] s1" _
       & " LEFT JOIN [Sheet2$] s2" _
       & "    ON s1.%GLAccountNumber_ColName% = s2.%GLAccountNumber_ColName%)" _
       & " LEFT JOIN [Sheet3$] s3" _
       & "    ON s3.%GLAccountNumber_ColName% = s1.% GLAccountNumber_ColName%)"

For Each var in Array("CompanyCode_ColName", "CompanyName_ColName", _
                      "GLAccountNumber_ColName", "GLAccountName_ColName", _
                      "EndingBalance1", "EndingBalance2", "EndingBalance3")

    strSQL = Replace(strSQL, "%" & var & "%", var)
Next var
```